# Rails, Controller Inheritance w Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using devise invitable: [gem on github](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable)

I want to implement controller inheritance, so I added a controller:

```
class InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  include Devise::Controllers::InternalHelpers

  before_filter :authenticate_inviter!, :only => [:new, :create]
  before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [:edit, :update]
  helper_method :after_sign_in_path_for

  # GET /resource/invitation/new
  def new
    build_resource
    render_with_scope :new
  end
..
.
```

And updated my routes to:

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:invitations => "invitations"}
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
"Template is missing
Missing template invitations/new with {:formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en], :handlers=>[:rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :erb, :rxml]} in view paths "/Users/bhellman/Sites/cline/app/views", "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/devise_invitable-0.3.5/app/views", "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/devise-1.1.3/app/views""
```

Can you help me understand what I did wrong with the routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know you have already had the right route and what you missed is the `views/invitations/new.html.erb` file.